# How to define props in Typescript when a parent component injects props in its children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint, react-tsx

When a component clones its children to inject props into them, how to define the children props type?

I'm receiving an error cause `injectedProps` is expected in `Child`

```
const Parent: React.SFC<ParentProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {React.cloneElement(children[0], { injectedProp: 'foo' })}
  </div>
);

const Child: React.SFC<ChildProps> = ({ injectedProp }) => (
  <div attr={injectedProp} />
);

type ChildProps = {
  injectedProp: string;
};
```

---

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

> Error in Child: `injectedProp` is missing

Comment: `injectedProp`  not included in `ChildProps`

Comment: I forgot to edit the type for SO :p

Comment: make it optional or give default parameter value

Answer (score 2):

This code pattern can't be typed properly in TypeScript and is ugly if you ask me.  Instead, consider passing a function that takes the injected prop and creates the final children:

```
interface ParentProps {
  children: (childProps: ChildProps) => React.ReactNode;
}

const Parent: React.SFC<ParentProps> = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children({ injectedProp: 'foo' })}
  </div>
);

const Child: React.SFC<ChildProps> = ({ injectedProp }) => (
  <div title={injectedProp} />
);

type ChildProps = {
  injectedProp: string;
};

function foo() {
  return <Parent>
    {childProps => <Child {...childProps} />}
  </Parent>
}
```